# What's usual success rate for neural network models?

Tags: neural-network

I am building a system with a NN trained for classification.

I am interested in what is error rate for systems you have built?

Classic example from [UCI ML](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/) is the Iris data set.
NN trained on it is almost perfect - error rate 0-1%; however it is a very basic dataset.

My network has following structure: 80in, 208hid, 2out. 
My result is 8% error rate on testing dataset.

Basically in this question I want to ask about various research results you encountered,
in your work, papers etc.

Addition 1:
  the error rate is of course on testing data - not training. So it is completely new dataset for the network

Addition 2 (from my comment under the question):
My new results. 1200 entries, 900 training, 300 testing. 85 in Class1, 1115 in Class2. Out of 85, 44 in testing set. Error rate - 6%. It is not so bad because 44 is ~15% of 300. So I am 2.5 times better..

Comment: This isn't really a question that can be easily answered.  The error rate is **highly** dependent on the data, the complexity of the NN, the amount of training, etc.  Some of those factors are also changeable, essentially allowing tuning of the error rate in cases where a low rate isn't the sole goal.

Comment: Exactly. I am asking about your final best result. I do not ask how to fix my network. This is kind of research results aggregator question.

Comment: Most questions here are more along the lines of "How can I fix this error?" rather than "research results aggregator," so I don't know that you'll get much useful input.  It sounds like your question could be adapted to that format by asking "What's a reasonable error rate for a real-world NN?", but the answer is "It depends what you're using it for."  Do you have a specific classification problem that you'd like to judge your results against?

Comment: yeah.. you are right. Yes, of course I have such a problem, but it is a bit hard to explain. In general I have classifier in really rare data set. Class 1 - 100 entities, Class 2 - 900. So, I wonder, what I can get from it..

Comment: With those numbers, you'd better get substantially better than 90% success, which is what you'd get just by always assigning to class 2. This is a great example of how the performance is data dependent.

Comment: Right.. but also, distribution of classes in training and testing set plays important part. My new results. 1200 entries, 900 training, 300 testin. 85 in C1, 1115 in C2. Out of 85, 44 in testing set. Error rate - 6%. It is not so bad because 44 is ~15% of 300. So I am 2.5 times better..

Answer (score 1):

Model performance is completely problem-specific.  Even among situations with similar quality and volumes of development data, with identical target variable definitions, performance can vary substantially.  Obviously, the more similar the problem definitions, the more likely the performance of different models are to match.

Another thing to consider is the difference between *technical performance* and *business performance*.  In some applications, an accuracy of 52% is tremendously profitable, whereas in other areas, and accuracy of 98% would be hopelessly low.

Answer (score 1):

Let me also add that besides what Predictor mentions, measuring your performance on the training set is usually useless as a guide to determine how your classifier would perform on previously unseen data. Many times with relatively simple classifiers you can get 0% error rate on the training set without learning anything useful (this is called overfitting).

What is more commonly used (and more helpful in determining how your classifier works) is either held out data or cross validation, even better if you separate your data in three: training, validating and testing.

Also it is very hard to get a sense of how good a classifier works from one threshold and giving only true positive + true negatives. People tend to also evaluate false positives and false negatives and plot ROC curves to see/evaluate the tradeoff. So, saying "2.5 times better" you should be clear that your comparing to a classifier that classifies everything as C2, which is a pretty crappy baseline.

Comment: Actually, now that I've re-read the original question, I think this is a very good point.  Your solution has 80 input variables, which is a lot!  Also, your hidden layer has over 200 nodes.  Assuming that the network is fully connected, that implies over 16,000 weights to set!  Apparent performance (performance on the training data) is meaningless: How well does your network do on holdout data?

Comment: @carlosdc - I am aware of overfitting. I always divide my data set to training and testing, so the error rate which I give you is from testing run. It would be huge if my network was overfitted. See my comment under the question with newest results.

Comment: @Predictor - My question did not stated that error rate is from testing run, not training. You are right, it would be useless, but it never happened in this case.

Comment: @user425720 i find it kind of confusing that you still say "My result is 8% error rate on training dataset.".

Comment: true, true, my English. Did not notice that. Will edit in a sec. :( sorry.

Comment: Detecting false neg and false pos is definitely way to go. Especially here -- Input is chemical data, very chaotic. I iterated over many versions of IN/HID/OUT and got again to less than ~10% Error rate.

Answer (score 0):

See for example this paper:

> Danilo P. Mandic and Jonathon A. Chanbers (2000). Towards the Optimal Learning Rate for
>   Backpropagation, *Neural Processing Letters 11: 1–5*. [PDF](http://www.commsp.ee.ic.ac.uk/~mandic/research/RNN_Stuff/Danilo_NPL_GNGD_2000.pdf)